# Matlab simulate quadcopter

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to simulate a quadcopter flight (x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw).
I need a simplest option to simulate/visualization - maybe 'X' / cross sign.
like this video: in 2:00 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvNzxVqqgnw

given  (x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw) , how can I simulate/visualization using the simplest way ?

I know how to plot 3d point with 'X' sign (using plot3)- but this thing doesn't control angles (roll,pitch,yaw) - is there a similar function that takes (x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw) ??

Thanks

Comment: This question is very broad and shows little effort on your part.

Comment: So you don't understand my question ? or you mean it's very general?

Comment: @user2824394 yes, it is too broad.

Comment: I know how to plot 3d point with 'X' sign (using plot3)- but this thing doesn't control angles (roll,pitch,yaw) - is there a similar function that takes (x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw) ??

Comment: @user2824393: Are you asking for a simulation or visualisation? Therse are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have the flight data ((x,y,z,roll,pitch,yaw) and simply want to display it.

Plot3 plots a single 3d point, which in itself cannot have pitch, roll, or yaw. It sounds like you will need to design a shape that can represent your quadcopter (a triangle of 3 points would do - anything with more than 1 dimension will. A square would probably be easiest), and then write a function that can compute the 3d coords of each point, given the coords of one of one of the points, and the pitch roll yaw data. Then use the plot3 to plot each point individually (and maybe add lines between them or something)

I realize this may not be helpful, but your question is extremely broad.